onBackPress can't load previous page on webView if use to load by postUrl()
i am trying to create an webView based android app.and can go back to the previous page by onBackPress. it is perfectly working when i using webview.loadUrl("url") as GET method. but wehen i using webView.postUrl("url", postData) to load as POST method then onBackPress can go back but can't load the previous page. i prefer to fetch any data using post method as secure.
is there any solution please!
I would like to load page by postUrl and onBackPress can load the previous page when trying to go back.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

try to use built-in methods - goBack() and canGoBack()

i used     if(webview.canGoBack()){ webview.goBack();} also.
